How will I know when to choose Е and when Э after the Russian letter Ж?
женщина — Е (stressed);
железо — Е (unstressed);
же (частица) — Е;
же (индейский народ в Бразилии) — Е;
жэ (название русской буквы) — Э;
межэтнический — Э;
ЖЭК — Э;
чжурчжэни — Э.
Seems not too easy for me!
I wonder: how does a Russian person (I am Russian as well) choose when to use Е and when to use Э? Does it always come purely intuitively?

ЖЕ is the rule. ЖЭ are exceptions:

ЖЭК, ЖЭЦ, etc. are initialisms (more of the same).
межэтнический, межэтажный, Воронежэнерго, Южэлектромонтаж are compounds. In compounds parts are simply put next to each other disregarding any spelling rules. Thus we get Минюст and постинфарктный vs предынфарктный.
чжурчжэни, Чжэцзян, жэнь – ЖЭ was probably chosen to emphasize their foreign nature. The Russian Wiktionary only has these two words containing ЧЖЭ and none having ЧЖЕ.
жэ (the name of the letter Ж), also spelled же – probably used to unify the series бэ, вэ, гэ, дэ...


Чжэцзян is simply the Cyrillic version of "Zhejiang", constructed according to the rules of Cyrillization of Chinese: zhe = чжэ, jiang = цзян. Just like Pinyin will create letter sequences that are unnatural in English (for example qixi), the Russian "Palladius" system (транскрипционная система Палладия) will create letter sequences that are unnatural in Russian.

In most cases "E" is used, "Э" is used in proper names and scientific terms.
